# Applying CSS formatting to Radio button outside of <form>

Tags: html, css, forms, input, radio-button

I am adding custom CSS to a tool that generates the HTML content for me. Unfortunately, it looks as though the tool generates radio buttons (`<input type="radio"`) outside of a `<form>` element. This causes issues because as mentioned in an answer to [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606657/radio-buttons-checked-attribute-not-working/41943819#41943819) if you do not have the `<form>` element you cannot apply the following code:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Here is an example of the code:

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio-answers">
  <label class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="d45ec94d-88cb-43bc-b4c9" placeholder="" class="" name="apt-trigger-radio-8c027e80-2df7-494a-a3a5" tabindex="31767">
    <div class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio-label">
      <div class="multi-survey-answer">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
          <!--td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
          -->
        </style>
        <span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:515,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:14281427},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Marketing - Individual Contributor&quot;}" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;">
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <style type="text/css">
            <!--td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
            -->
          </style>
          <span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:515,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:13228792},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Individual&quot;}" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;">Individual</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="ae74981b-6395-4718-89ca" placeholder="" class="" name="apt-trigger-radio-8c027e80-2df7-494a-a3a5" tabindex="31768">
    <div class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio-label">
      <div class="multi-survey-answer">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
          <!--td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
          -->
        </style>
        <span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:515,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:14281427},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Product Marketing - Individual Contributor&quot;}" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;">Manager</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="c6a9fdfd-aed4-4bb9-9300" placeholder="" class="" name="apt-trigger-radio-8c027e80-2df7-494a-a3a5" tabindex="31769">
    <div class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio-label">
      <div class="multi-survey-answer">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
          <!--td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
          -->
        </style>
        <span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:515,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:14281427},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Finance - Individual Contributor&quot;}" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;">
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <style type="text/css">
            <!--td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
            -->
          </style>
          <span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:515,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:13228792},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Director&quot;}" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;">Director</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="285ddfff-4be4-4c23-9f26" placeholder="" class="" name="apt-trigger-radio-8c027e80-2df7-494a-a3a5" tabindex="31770">
    <div class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio-label">
      <div class="multi-survey-answer">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
          <!--td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
          -->
        </style>
        <span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:515,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:14281427},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;CSM - Manager&quot;}" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;">
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <style type="text/css">
            <!--td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
            -->
          </style>
          <span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:515,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:13228792},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;VP / SVP&quot;}" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;">VP / SVP</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <label class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio">
    <input type="radio" value="d99a91b3-ac39-4534-bf6b" placeholder="" class="" name="apt-trigger-radio-8c027e80-2df7-494a-a3a5" tabindex="31771">
    <div class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio-label">
      <div class="multi-survey-answer">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
          <!--td {border: 1px solid #cccccc;}br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
          -->
        </style>
        <span data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:515,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:13228792},&quot;12&quot;:0}" data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;C Level&quot;}" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;font-style:normal;">C Level</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Is there a workaround for this? I requested the software be adjusted to include the `<form>` element but that could take months/years.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can apply CSS styling to a radio button outside of a `<form>` element?

Just to make things even more fun, I can only use CSS, and not JavaScript or HTML

Comment: as far as I know, that CSS works just fine also without a form element. Could you add a snippet in your question (both CSS and markup) and show the issue?

Comment: Good idea @FabrizioCalderan - have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `input[type="radio"]:checked + label` is looking for a `label` who is an immediate **sibling** of a `:checked` radio input, but your markup actually is

```
<label class="apt-survey-multi-choice-radio">
    <input type="radio" ...>
    ...
</label>
```

So you need to target a `label` that **contains** a `:checked` radio input, and you could use `:has()`

```css
label:has([type="radio"]:checked) {
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" />
    Label
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, it looks like the CSS editor doesn't accept ()! Any thoughts on an alternative method?